php variable not handling variables with spaces in them as it should
I am trying to get my mysql database to update a value in a column when a checkbox is checked/unchecked. This works for 1 word variable, but somehow refuses when the checkbox that is checked has 2 words (in other words, has a space in the string).
The list of checkboxes in the form is taken from the database which holds the name used for the checkbox name field and the actual text displayed.
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input filter_check" value="<?= $row['buttons_allowed_activated']; ?>" name="<?= $row['Service']; ?>" id="labels" <?php if ($activate_status == 1) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>><?= $row['Service'];?> 

This works flawlesly and there are no issues when it comes to values like "My Value" taken from the database Service column.
From there the edit document takes over when the form is posted (as usual) and there I check on every Service (by Service name as it comes from the database in the checkbox fields) if the checkbox was checked or not:
$checkboxes_array = array();
$unset_value = array();

if (isset($_POST['Service1'])) {
    $checkboxes_array[] = 'Service1';
} else {
    $unset_values[] = 'Service1';
}
        
if (isset($_POST['My Service2'])) {
    $checkboxes_array[] = 'My Service2';
} else {
    $unset_values[] = 'My Service2';
}

if (isset($_POST['Service3'])) {
    $checkboxes_array[] = 'Service3';
} else {
    $unset_values[] = 'Service3';
}

I then loop over them as the idea of this form is to enable/disable Services on the homepage. This is done by looping over both the $unset_values array as the $checkboxes_array to know which ones should have the enabled tag (1) set in the database or which ones should be set to disabled (0).
foreach ($checkboxes_array as &$checkbox){
    $button_set_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id WHERE (buttons_allowed_userid) IN ('".$userId."') AND (Service) IN ('".$checkbox."') ");
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($button_set_results)){
        $button_set_service = $rows['Service'];
            
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id set buttons_allowed_activated = 1 where Service = '".$button_set_service."' and buttons_allowed_userid = '".$userId."' ");
    }
}       
        
foreach( $unset_values as &$unset_value ){
    $button_unset_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id WHERE (buttons_allowed_userid) IN ('".$userId."') AND (Service) IN ('".$unset_value."') ");
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($button_unset_results)){
        $button_unset_service = $rows['Service'];
        
        $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id set buttons_allowed_activated = 0 where Service = '".$button_unset_service."' and buttons_allowed_userid = '".$userId."' ");
    }
} 

From what I am seeing, it just doesn't make sense that I am unable to set the disabled tag (buttons_allowed_activated) to 0 for the strings with a space in them while I am unable to set them as enabled. The code is exactly the same except for the array used and the value set for the buttons_allowed_activated column.
What am I missing here or what am I doing wrong?
I checked if the values in the arrays are correct and in line with the Service column, which they are.
I tried the call in the database itself and that works normally and actually sets the value to 1 as it should:
UPDATE buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id set buttons_allowed_activated = 1 where Service = 'My Service2' and buttons_allowed_userid = '{user id for testing purposes}'

Example from the database:



buttons_allowed_id
buttons_allowed_userid
buttons_allowed_button_id
buttons_allowed_activated
button_id
Service
button_href
button_type




19
28
1
0
1
Plex
{HTML Button code for Plex}
media


20
28
2
1
2
Ombi
{HTML Button code for Ombi}
media


25
28
7
0
7
Home Assistant
{HTML Button code for Home Assistant}
server


28
28
10
0
10
Pi-Hole Main
{HTML Button code for Pi-Hole Main}
server



var_dump() of the processed values (from the example table so you can see both the ones with issues and the ones working). In this case I checked Home Assistant but did not check Pi-Hole Main, so the Pi-Hole Main would be valid now, but even if I did check it, it would still say false just like Home Assistant, while the ones without spaces are giving a true back when they are checked in the form
string(4) "Plex" bool(true) string(4) "Ombi" bool(true) string(14) "Home Assistant" bool(false) string(12) "Pi-Hole Main" bool(false) 

As stated, the form loops over the entries in the database to create the list/form so there should be no difference between the ones without spaces and the ones with. Both should report as true when checked, but still the ones with spaces in the name refuse to do so resulting in being removed from the activated list in the database (checked or not).
SOLUTION:
After lots of troubleshooting and asking help of somebody outside Stack Overflow, I finally found the solution to be the fact that PHP was changing the spaces in the variables with an _.
["Home_Assistant"]=> string(14) "Home Assistant"

Therefor I changed the isset to in_array which solved the problem :)
the full solution code for who has the same issues:
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    
    if (isset($_POST['edit-enabled-submit'])) {

        require 'dbh.inc.php';

        $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
        $username = $_SESSION['userUid'];

        $services = ['Plex', 'Moviematch', 'Home Assistant', 'Proxmox', 'Pi-Hole Main', 'Pi-Hole Slave', 'Mealie', 'Spoolman', 'Klipper'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE buttons_allowed INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id SET buttons_allowed_activated = ? where Service = ? and buttons_allowed_userid = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $status, $service, $userId);

        foreach ($services as $service) {
            $status = in_array($service, $_POST, true) ? 1 : 0;
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
    
    header("Location: ../");
    exit();
}


Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Why do you use IN instead of = when you're just testing a single value?

I can't see any reason why your code would work differently for the checked and unset values.

Probably unrelated to your problem, but using foreach with references via foreach ($checkboxes_array as &$checkbox){} is very rarely needed, and more likely to cause you headaches down the road.

Although you should 100% switch over to prepared statements, until you do, instead of building a string and executing it directly, assign the string to a variable so that you can inspect it first.

I don't see why you need the SELECT queries. You're only selecting one Service row, and just updating that same row. I suspect the problem is that the row doesn't exist when starting, so there's nothing to update. You probably want INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

@Barmar first of all, yeah I know I need to use prepared statements, but as my knowledge of php/mysql is pretty low, I want to get the basic working first before I go over my head with this. As for the SELECT I started this before I moved over to having the variable set in the array itself, so yeah that could be removed, but I am not updating a row that doesn't exist as I am able to set the activated part to 0 to begin with (and don't delete the row).

Then I'm back to my original comment -- the only difference between the two is whether you do buttons_allowed_activated = 0 or buttons_allowed_activated = 1. There's no reason why they should work differently.

I wouldn't use two different arrays and loops. Use an associative array where the value is whether the button should be activated or not. Then you can use SET buttons_allowed_activated = ? where the corresponding value comes from the value in the array.

@ChrisHaas I did test this part out in a test environment: https://onlinephp.io/c/06c24 I started with using the $_POST part to save the value in the array, but that is probably due to me doing something wrong :) so that is why I for now swapped to hardcoded instead of the variable in the array part, but it does work as expected

@Barmar sorry for asking, but how would you do this? I was kinda already proud I managed to do this, let alone know how to use/setup an associative array, so an example on how you would do this would be very nice :)


you should test on phpize.online, using database as well. 2. If your query doesn't match, it means that values in the query and database do not match. This is called logic.


@YourCommonSense I get that, but as I stated, the checkboxes in the form are taken from the database, so there can't be any query that doesn't match, but still it matches on update for strings without spaces and fails the ones with for some reason while the exact service is taken from the database entry itself during the same loop as the one with no spaces. It just doesn't make sense... And the reason for closing this question is also not valid as reported duplicate question doesn't hold a solution for my problem.

Anything doesn't make sense until you start debugging it. and the dupe question tells you exactly THAT

Which I did already if you read my post and comments... There is no reason any of the suggestions is the cause of this in my case. And running the query manually works flawlessly with the values that the php code is inserting into the query.

"I did test this part out in a test environment" - I'm not seeing any SQL there. Build the SQL string and print it out to the screen so that you can copy and paste it, unchanged, into a testing tool.

@ChrisHaas as mentioned in my edit, the return from the var_dump shows what is being saved. The query is setup correctly, but the problem is that somehow the form is not seeing the checkbox being checked and therefor the boolean is empty when I set the variable with isset. So what I would need to find out is why the checkbox is seen as not checked while it is checked when pressing save settings. And the weird thing is that the value and name for that checkbox is taken straight from the database with <?= $row['Service']; ?>

I would simplify this, by using just a single loop and query.
$services = ['Service1', 'My Service2', 'Service3'];
$userid = '{user id for testing purposes}';

$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    UPDATE buttons_allowed
    INNER JOIN buttons ON buttons_allowed.buttons_allowed_button_id=buttons.button_id
    SET buttons_allowed_activated = ? where Service = ? and buttons_allowed_userid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $enabled, $service, $userid);

foreach ($services as $service) {
    $enabled = isset($_POST[$service]);
    $stmt->execute();
}

Using the prepared statement should avoid any problems with special characters in the service name.

Thx for the example! But as you use the isset, wouldn't that only change disabled to enabled and leave enabled as enabled when you don't check a checkbox? But you are right, this really simplifies it a lot!

With all due respect, this code doesn't answer this question. Spaces do not break queries. It you want to suggest an irrelevant improvement, you can write this code on some online shell such as phpize.online and give a link in the comments.

oke, I see why this works now, the isset makes it a 0 when it is not set, that is pretty clever! But what I just noticed is that when I edit anything that does work, it will disable the ones with a space in it. So somehow it keeps those as state 0 in the enabled part. What I find strange the most is that it does find the service in the lookup, but it fails to see the check on the checkbox somehow in order to set the $_POST part

@YourCommonSense I know that. As I said in comments, I couldn't see any reason why the spaces were only breaking one of the queries. But if nothing else this shows how to do it using prepared statements, and simplification should also make troubleshooting easier. They also asked in the comments how to implement my suggestion.

@FGOD Is it still only failing for the unchecked boxes? I can't see why unless the value of Service doesn't really match. Could there be differences in case, or the number of spaces?

yeah still the same results. If I edit 1 and save the list, it disables all the ones with a space in the service column. All 3 have 1 space in the column entry (Home Assistant, Pi-Hole Main and Pi-Hole Slave in the exact case). I just don't get it as the data is being extracted in the form from that column, so it should set the variable like all the rest, but somehow it fails to set making it a value of 0 on the enabled part (that is the most logical thing I can think of why this happens, I just can't see why as the others just succeed and are being looped on during the same loop)

Please edit the question with sample original table contents, the result of var_dump($_POST), and the expected result.

@Barmar thx for your help with looking into this. I have edited the question with actual database data/ column return from the inner join used and var_dump() for both the $enabled and $service variables during the foreach loop. Hopefully this helps with more insight, because I really don't get it...

Why are we joining with buttons when everything that's needed is in the buttons_allowed table?

well, not everything is in there. The Service name is in buttons, and as I have to compare either the button id of the service or the service name itself, I will have to join that in some fashion to know which buttons that needs to be enabled for each account

OK, but I don't see why it should affect whether my query works.

well, the query itself is fine, the problem seems to be the fact that even when that checkbox with services with spaces in the name gets checked or not, is not being passed as checked by the form, resulting in a false on the boolean check from the isset. I just don't see why that fails to transfer from the form when there is a space in the name... The moment I change the service name in the database to something without spaces, the form just works again for that particular service (for example, changing Home Assistant to HA instead and it starts picking up the checkbox again)

All I can think of is that the names with spaces don't actually match what's in the DB. Maybe you have something like non-breaking space in one place instead of regular space.

But that should still affect activated and non-activated equally. None of this makes sense as far as I can tell.

Yeah exactly, it shouldn't matter for the way the form deals with checkboxes being checked or not

@Barmar I have found the problem and solution with help from somebody at work :) The problem was the fact that PHP itself changed the space into _ and therefor it didn't match anymore resulting in false eventhough the checkbox was checked. I changed the code to use in_array instead of isset and that resulted in a working query again :) See my question edit for the solution :) thx for helping me troubleshoot this though!

PHP doesn't change spaces into underscore by itself. That must be coming from some code you've written or a library you're using.
